# How to store disabled element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Please go through sample code.

**Html Code:**

```
<div class="OuterDiv">
 <div id="child1">
 </div>
 <div id="child2" style="display:none">
 </div>
</div>
```

**WebDriver Code:-**

```
List<WebElement> list1 = WebDriver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[class='OuterDiv'] div"));
for(WebElement element : list1)
{
 sysout(element.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Using this code I'm trying to get ID's of all `div`s but element having `display:none` isn't stored in the list. So I'm not able to get ID for that `div`. I have to scan all the elements again when that element becomes visible. I should I do to store it even when it is `display: none`.

Comment: Is the `html` is exactly as in the page? or did you write it manually?

Comment: I write it manually. The original code is bit complex.

Comment: In the original is it `<div> id="child2" style="display:none">` with `>` after the `div`?

Comment: Are you sure its not stored? This code should work. Try to go over this in debug instead of printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like:

```
    List<WebElement> divList = WebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[class='OuterDiv']")).findElements(By.tagName("div"));
    for(WebElement element : divList)
    {
       if(element.getAttribute("style").equals("display:none"));
       {
          divList.add(element);
          sysout(element.getAttribute("id"));
       }
    }
```

Comment: Ok I will try this. but I guess that element is not stored in List. thats the reason I m not able to access it.

Comment: it will store it to list when it's will find it. one very impotent thing to remember that you sore the reference of the elements! every DOM change you will need to initialize the list ones again for be able to use it.

Comment: Hi, I made changes as per the suggestion but in the loop Webdriver donot find any element (having display:none). I think first time when i store elements, webdriver skip that one element. What m i suppose to do to store that element at first scan?

Comment: webdriver didn't skip them i think they didn't exist when you store the div elements, you adding wait to the driver ? driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: if you doing findElements(By.tagName("div")) it's taking all div elements it's see it can be or the dive elements in different frame or still didn't appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
List<WebElement> list1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("div.OuterDiv div")));
for(WebElement element : list1)
{
 System.out.println(element.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Hope it will work..:)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is designed to interact with elements like a user would. Since users can't interact with invisible elements, Selenium will not interact with them. That's why you only get the visible elements in your collection. There are ways around this... for example using `JavascriptExecutor`. If you are trying to accomplish a user scenario then you will want to do what a user would do to expose the element you want to get access to. For example, open a popup or expand a section on the page. Doing things like this will expose otherwise hidden elements but still stay within a user scenario. Using `JavascriptExecutor` is executing JS on the page which a user is NOT going to do so if you use it, it's no longer a user scenario but it has its uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the outer tag to retrive the element, and use xpath to retrieve all sub elements like below:

```
WebElement outterDiv = WebDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[class='OuterDiv']"));
List<WebElement> innerElements = outterDiv.FindElements(By.Xpath(".//*"));
for(WebElement element : innerElements)
{
   sysout(element.getAttribute("id"));
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thank you.